# Rolling the File in windows using API

Tags: windows, mfc, windows-ce, ntfs, visual-c++

How to do file rolling in windows depending upon size? I know that log4net and log4cxx does this but I want to do this for another purpose so is there any API available there in windows?

Thanks,
Omky

Answer (score 0):

I would just use log4net.  It doesn't necessarily have to be for logging purposes and as you say, the rolling file appender is built in.